# Why is ddebug_backtrace coming up blank?

Tags: debugging

I've been using the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module for a couple of years now but every time I try to get a backtrace I run into issues.  I remember getting it working once, but I don't remember how.

It seems like using `dpm(ddebug_backtrace());` should do the trick.  I have tried it with no argument, `TRUE`, and `FALSE`, and I have also tried removing the dpm function it's wrapped in.

I have dpm calls directly above and below this code that print variables appropriately, but the most I get out of `dpm(ddebug_backtrace());` is a blank line in the Krumo output.

Suggestions mightily appreciated.

Comment: `dpm(ddebug_backtrace());` works fine for me (I just tried it). Does `die(ddebug_backtrace());` work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see the source, you can see that ddebug_backtrace() only returns values if the variable error_level is set to 1 or greater.

```
// Show message if error_level is ERROR_REPORTING_DISPLAY_SOME or higher.
// (This is Drupal's error_level, which is different from $error_level,
// and we purposely ignore the difference between _SOME and _ALL,
// see #970688!)
if (variable_get('error_level', 1) >= 1) {
```

So one of the ways to make it return values is by either changing the error_level from admin/config/development/logging, or change it temporarily in the code like so:

```
variable_set('error_level', 1);
dpm(ddebug_backtrace(TRUE));
variable_set('error_level', 1);
```

As Ian Bullock says, debug_backtrace() would return values because it ignores the variable and the content is essentially the same. But ddebug_backtrace() returns a more readable output.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, this actually answers the question.

Answer (score 8):

For me the command had to be called without the extra `d`

`dpm(debug_backtrace());`

Comment: This worked for me.  I'm on D7.

Answer (score 1):

In the instances where I've been like, "WTF! Where's my dpm output at?", it's either been:

1. A permissions issue with an impersonated user not having `access devel information` perm.
2. A theme page that isn't outputting the `$messages` var.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks shawn, gets a vote because it's good advice, sadly I've already been through that.  As I said, dpm is outputting fine but not when used with `ddebug_backtrace()`.